# How can i Pass variable in node js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

I am using server with node js. I trying to do recognition(at aws) on picture that come from my client angular.
The code does'nt identify the variable picture when i pass it.
with the function path Upload-ng the picture is undefined, and this is my problem.

This is my code:

```
var picture;
  app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var data_stream = fs.createReadStream(req.body.filename);
    var s3 = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: 'aws-connect-angular', Key: req.body.filename + Date.now() } });
    s3.putObject({ Body: data_stream}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) 
          handleError(err, res);
        else     
          handleSuccess(data, res);
    })
  });
  // upload file to s3 using the angular app

  var upload = multer({
      storage: multerS3({
          acl: 'public-read',
          s3: new AWS.S3(),
          bucket: 'aws-connect-angular',
          key: function (req, file, cb) {
              console.log('file to upload: ' + file.originalname);
          picture =  Date.now() + file.originalname;
            console.log('my picture: ' + picture);
              // in order not to overwrite other users files that have the same name 
              // cb(null, picture+ file.originalname);
              cb(null, picture);
          }
      })
  });

  // this will upload a file from the angular app
  app.post('/upload-ng', upload.array('file', 1), function(req, res) {
       var resp = useRecognitaion(picture);
    // res.send({ file: req.file });
    
    console.log(resp)
    res.send({ result: resp });
  });

  
   function useRecognitaion(picture)
  {
        console.log("in recognition");
         console.log(picture);
    var rekognition = new AWS.Rekognition();
    var params = {
            Image: {
            S3Object: {
            Bucket: "aws-connect-angular", 
            Name: picture
            }
            }, 
          
        };
    rekognition.detectText(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);//handleError(err, err); // an error occurred
    else    { console.log(data);
              return(data);      
            }     // successful response
 
    });  
  }
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please use `let` or `const` instead of `var`

Comment: If `picture` is undefined at the time you try to use it in your API call to Rekognition, then your line of code that sets the value of `picture` has not yet executed. You should debug why that is, likely because of the async nature of JavaScript and you have not waited for the completion of an async call that would result in `picture` being set.